# Django how to add an instance to reversed ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have 2 classes:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=255)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="phone_numbers", null=True, blank=True)
```

When I would like to get a phone number for a contact I can just do this:

```
contact = Contact.objects.all()[0]
contact_phones = contact.phone_numbers.all()
```

No sweat here. 
Now I would like to know what the proper way would be to set a new phone number for a contact.

I have tried to do this:

```
foo = Contact.objects.create(name="Foo")
contact_phone = PhoneNumber.objects.create(phone="123456789", contact=foo)
```

This does save the contact and the phone number, but I would just like to be able to create a method inside the Contact class like `add_phone()` or something like that.

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create) method of the reverse manager.

```
foo.phone_numbers.create(phone='123456789')
```